# Unable to include ASM header file in C without losing preprocessor

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, c-preprocessor, inline-assembly

Short version:

I want to be able to define assembler macros in a `macros.S` and use them from inside `asm()` statements in GNU C.

I can do this with `asm(".include \"macros.S\"");` near the top of my C source, but I want `macros.S` to go through the C preprocessor.

---

Long version:

In GCC asm, `*.S` files are preprocessed by the C preprocessor, allowing use of C style `#define`, etc.

In GCC C, you can include an asm header file (which may include asm macro definitions, `.set` declarations, etc), by writing `asm(".include \"myasmheader.S\"");` near the top of a file.

Including an ASM header file in this manner allows you to use asm macros inside asm blocks.

Unfortunately, doing so does not invoke the C preprocessor on the `.S` file being included (as the `.include` is done later in the compilation process), and so `#define`s are no longer substituted.

So is there any way to properly include a `.S` file inside of a C file?

Some other compilers support:

```
#asm
#include "myasmheader.S"
#endasm
```

Which would not exhibit such a problem. But alas, GCC seems to require that all asm inside of a C file is in the form of strings.

Short of not using asm (not an option, embedded DSP project that heavily mixes asm and c), or removing use of the C preprocessor in ASM files, what can be done?

Comment: Preprocess it manually with `cpp` as a distinct build step.

Comment: It took me a while to figure out exactly what you were asking, so I wrote a short version of the question for the benefit of future readers.  This makes some of the rest of the text redundant, but I didn't want to just delete big chunks of it.

Comment: about arrowd suggestion -> yes, produce `myasmheader.s` from `myasmheader.S` first in separate build step, then `.include \"myasmheader.s\"` in C file. (if you are on some weird obsolete OS, which has case insensitive file system, use different extensions, the `s` vs `S` is common with gcc on *NIX systems, where file names are case sensitive).

Comment: @arrowd Yes I believe that would work. I'll give it a go, if someone wants to write it up as an answer I'll accept it otherwise I'll post it here for future reference. Thanks for the help, appreciated :)

Comment: @Mania Please do post your own answer. I'd appreciate getting this out of the list of unanswered questions.

Answer (score 2):

From the comments:

Add preprocessing of the ASM file (via `cpp`) as a distinct build step into whatever build system you're using.

<sub>Credits to [arrowd](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47532444/7311767#comment82021365_47532444) and [Ped7g](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47532444/7311767#comment82022121_47532444).</sub>